# JQ JSON - Values to Array

Tags: json, bash, jq

## A confusion of getting to the bottom of a jq parse.

I'm learning, apreciate your help.

Two arrays here, both with same type ouput result, just integer values (spaced), same for string values.

Ex: 1 2 3 4 5

A multi-nested weather dump:
I  trying to understand to return just an index ([0...]) value or/and an array to sort - json and/or bash of the values. I've tried, and yes have read the man, jq i'm loving, just ?...

#Query 1

```
drp=$(cat "$HOME/..." | jq '.DailyForecasts[].Day.RainProbability | .')
```

JSON: -- The query above works fine gives integer output, there are 5 array sets so 5 digits: number number number number number - space separated, no [] .

```
  "Day": {
    "Icon": 2,
    "IconPhrase": "Mostly sunny",
    "HasPrecipitation": false,
    "ShortPhrase": "Mostly sunny and breezy",
    "LongPhrase": "Mostly sunny and breezy",
    "PrecipitationProbability": 1,
    "ThunderstormProbability": 0,
    "RainProbability": 1,
    "SnowProbability": 0,
    "IceProbability": 0,
    "Wind": {
      "Speed": {
        "Value": 15,
        "Unit": "mi/h",
        "UnitType": 9
 
    ...
    }
```

#Query 2:
Ive tried to map, etc, number of ways (ex. going for the grass value).

JSON: -- Same description as Query 1

```
apg=$(cat "$HOME/..." | jq '.DailyForecasts[].AirAndPollen | .[1] | .Value | .')

"AirAndPollen": [
    {
      "Name": "AirQuality",
      "Value": 44,
      "Category": "Good",
      "CategoryValue": 1,
      "Type": "Ozone"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Grass",
      "Value": 12,
      "Category": "Moderate",
      "CategoryValue": 2
    },
        ... 
    ]
```

Comment: What do contain `"$HOME/..."``?

Comment: It would help if you could provide a sample json string and explain what is the expected output.

Comment: $ Home is just the working directory, irrelevant. The two JQ queries are potsted there with the relevant JSON. As said I get a response output (example as shown) to that point in the JSON feed. so there is just somthing simple Not correct in my queries. As said the outputs are just coming out as spaced integers.